# C# appointmentItem Recurrences occurrences display

Tags: c#, outlook, appointment

I have a "tiny" problem with C#.

I am developing an outlook plug-in. Basically when you click on a button on the ribbon (on an appointment with a periodicity) it just tries to make some treatment (irrelevant here), then if it doesn't succeed and if the occurrences are more than 5, it does the following:

```
RecurrencePattern recpat = this.item.GetRecurrencePattern();
recpat.Occurences = 5;
```

At this point there are 5 occurrences. BUT on the display on the window, the dates for the meeting are not updating to 5 occurrences. The place you see the dates "Every Tuesday from XX/06/2017 to XX/08/2017" for example stay still.

If i save the appointment it updates but it is saved (which i want the user to do), if I close and open a new interceptor (window) it updates but it stops the treatment I want to make afterwards.

I tried the this.UpdateLayout() method but it doesn't work.

I'm a bit lost after a day of active search on this one. It appears that on here nobody is trying to do some modification and wait for the user to save them. I found lot of documentation but for people who wanted to create and save the appointment right after that without prompting the user.

I thought that it was a two-way binding but it seems not. Then i thought maybe it's a known problem with outlook 2010 (professional computers ...) but I didn't found any clue on this one.

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do - Outlook syncs various properties when the item is saved.

Comment: Well then ... Thanks for the answer